# How can I paste the clipboard content from the Chrome remote desktop desktop (CRD) client to the computer running the CRD server that I connected to?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google, remote-control, copy-paste

I use the [Chrome remote desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.chromeremotedesktop)
Android application.

How can I paste the clipboard content from the Android Chrome remote desktop client to the computer running the Chrome remote desktop server that I connected to?

When I press on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> using the Hacker's keyboard when connected to the host, it doesn't retrieve the Android clipboard. Also I didn't see any option in Chrome remote desktop to send the clipboard content.